# Is a graph with only one node a connected graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I need to know if a graph contain only a single node is considered a connected graph.

Comment: A connected component is non-empty, so a graph with a single node has only one connected component, i.e. is connected.

Comment: Yes. (It's either connected or disconnected...)

Answer (score 3):

A connected graph is a graph for which there exists a path from one vertex to any distinct vertex. Since the graph containing only a single vertex has no distinct vertices it is vacuously true that the graph containing only a single vertex is connected.